# Nuxt: how to prevent nuxt-link goes to another page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to stop `nuxt-link` going to another page.

This is my code

```
<nuxt-link :to="item.url" data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link" v-b-toggle="'collapse-'+index" :ref="'parent-'+index" @click.native="toggleSubMenuIcon(index)">


methods: {
    toggleSubMenuIcon(index) {
      this.$store.dispatch('layout/TOGGLE_SUBMENU_ICON', index)
    }
  }
```

I need a similar e.preventDefault() to block browser to visit the page at item.url

I has tried also

```
<nuxt-link :to="item.url" data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link" v-b-toggle="'collapse-'+index" :ref="'parent-'+index" @click.native="toggleSubMenuIcon(index), event => event.preventDefault()">
```

without success.

I would not use a simple "hash" into the url 'cause I don't like it printed in the URL browser.

Thank you

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561723/19901666 and adapt to it by your needs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try to add `event=""`, its work for me

```
<nuxt-link event="" :to="item.url" data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link" v-b-toggle="'collapse-'+index" :ref="'parent-'+index" @click.native="toggleSubMenuIcon(index), event => event.preventDefault()">
```

Comment: this is so strange. i had a **NuxtLink** that was working perfectly when defined like so: `<NuxtLink :to="myURL" @click.prevent="myFunction">link</NuxtLink>`. however, somewhere along the way, the event capturing stopped working and now only works after i've updated it to:`<NuxtLink :to="myURL" event="" @click.native="myFunction(), event => event.preventDefault()">link</NuxtLink>`... i don't understand why, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: This works for me. I wanted a link that was "alive" in all other ways other than allowing the click event, so that someone could open it via right-click, for example. FYI this is a Vue Router thing, and it works with Vue Router 3 (Vue2/Nuxt2). When upgrading to Vue3/Nuxt3 and Vue Router 4, you'll have to use a different way; see docs here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link