# Click on link, run function then redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have three nuxt-links on a page. By clicking on each link a method is called which returns a String as a result of some calculations.This string should be set as the query in :to.

BUt before that method is done the page redirects to a new address. Is there any way to prevent redirecting before new query is calculated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuxt: how to prevent nuxt-link goes to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885664/nuxt-how-to-prevent-nuxt-link-goes-to-another-page)

Comment: For help writing better questions that get upvotes instead of down, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Phil In fact I don't want to prevent going to another page. I want to run a function and after it returns, redirect to a new page.

Comment: Sounds like you _do_ want to prevent the default click action which is to navigate to another page. That seems to be what they're doing in the linked post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on the answer provided in [Nuxt: how to prevent nuxt-link goes to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885664/nuxt-how-to-prevent-nuxt-link-goes-to-another-page), you can add `event=""` to your link to prevent it from navigating.

Then you can add a *native* click handler to calculate the appropriate query string and push the new route to the router.

For example

```html
<NuxtLink
  to="/foo"
  event=""
  @click.native="calculateQueryParams('/foo')"
>
  Foo
</NuxtLink>
```

```js
methods: {
  calculateQueryParams(path) {
    const query = {
      foo: performance.now(),
    }
 
    this.$router.push({ path, query })
  },
},
```

[image: Edit stupefied-lalande-8zp52]

Comment: This works, but what exactly does event="" do? There is not much about it in the nuxt docs...

Comment: <router-link>'s event prop is deprecated and has been removed in Vue Router 4. Use the v-slot API to remove this warning: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link.