# Nuxt : @click does not work with Nuxt-link

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am expecting to include on my web application an effect that underlines the section where we are in the list of sections.
I am working with Nuxt.

I don't know why the following code does not change the value of the boolean `isActive`.

```html
<nuxt-link
  :to="`${path}/${filterItem.filter}`"
  :style='{"text-decoration": (isActive ? "underline" : "none")}'
  @click="selectSeason(filterItem.filter) toggleUnderline()" >
```

```js
methods: {
  selectSeason(filter) {
    this.$router.push(`${this.path}/${filter}`)
  },
  toggleUnderline() {
   this.isActive = !this.isActive
  }
},
```

Comment: Nuxt link have its own class active and you can use it to change style.

Comment: A link is supposed to make you move, not trigger an action. Use a `button` for that purpose.

Comment: Also, please try to use it like `selectSeason(filterItem.filter); toggleUnderline()`, with a `;` in between the 2 methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably achieve this with something like this

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-link to="/about" :custom="true">
    <a @click="test">go to about page</a>
  </nuxt-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log('called test method')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

As shown here: https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/846#issuecomment-808150258

Even thought, this is probably not the best approach overall and seems quite too hacky for a simple use case.
Use a `button` tag if you want an action, otherwise put conditional logic on your route but don't mix a client side navigation and some kind of click events.

Answer (score 2):

Same as router-link, you need to use `v-on:click.native`

```html
<nuxt-link
  :to="`${path}/${filterItem.filter}`"
  :style='{"text-decoration": (isActive ? "underline" : "none")}'
  @click.native="selectSeason(filterItem.filter) toggleUnderline()" 
>
</nuxt-link>
```

[How do we v-on:click nuxt-link?](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1786#issuecomment-334446353)

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt3:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const anyFunction = () => {
    console.log('easy')
  }
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLink
    :to="'/'"
    @click.prevent="anyFunction()"
  >easy</NuxtLink>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt3 `<NuxtLink>` will get a `class="router-link-active router-link-exact-active"` if it's active, so you can use those to underline active link.