# How to trigger a click event on a nuxt-link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to fire the pushBreadcrumb method on a nuxt-link. However, I am unable to trigger the method despite using @click.native as suggested at: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1786

```
    <nuxt-link
      :to="linkTo"
      class="folder-card flex p-4 rounded border"
      @click.native="pushBreadcrumb"
    >
      <content></content>
    </nuxt-link>
```

Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you searched for this before posting? This seems to be doing that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776444/8816585

Comment: was going to say that you probably should add some html tag inside nuxt-link to trigger @click event