# Trigger another click event inside nuxt-link

Tags: vue.js, events, nuxt.js, click

```html
<div>
  <nuxt-link to="/home">
    <h1>Title text</h1>
    <p>Product description</p>
    <p @click.stop="addCart()">Add to cart</p>
  </nuxt-link>
</div>
```

I'm not able to click my `addCart` function. If I click it's just redirecting to home page.

Comment: I'm not sure that to add an item to a cart, that an `a` tag is the way to go. I recommend rather using a `button`. But if you still want that behavior, give a try to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776444/8816585

Comment: @kissu still not working

Comment: Hi, please be more specific on what is not working and you tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
@click.prevent="addCart()"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by `prevent` event modifier in [vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers)

```
@click.prevent="addCart()
```

or

```
<div>
    <nuxt-link to="/home">
        <h1>Title text</h1>
        <p>Product description</p>
        <p @click.prevent="addCart()">Add to cart</p>
    </nuxt-link>
</div>
```