# @click event not firing on nuxt-link in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

According to this `Nuxt 2` [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885664/nuxt-how-to-prevent-nuxt-link-goes-to-another-page) this should prevent `nuxt-link` from navigating to a new page:

```
<nuxt-link :to="`/meet`" class="group font-normal" @click.native="event => event.preventDefault()" event="">
```

but it doesn't. The function inside `@click` is not executed and nuxt navigates to `/meet` url.

Any idea how to execute `@click` events on a `nuxt 3 link`?

Comment: the .native modifier has been remove in Vue 3 [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html)

Comment: Not sure if that one still works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776444/8816585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `prevent` modifier  and remove `:to` prop:

```html
<nuxt-link  class="group font-normal" @click.prevent="yourEventHandler" event="">
```

then use `this.$router.push()` inside your event handler

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help. The link still navigates.

Comment: Try to remove `:to` prop and use `this.$router.push()` in the event handler

Comment: I guess this works, although it really defeats the purpose of the `nuxt-link` element. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Could you add your second approach to the answer for future visitors?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov if your thing is not moving to another page, it should not be a link anyway but a button.

Comment: @kissu Inside my navigation I want to display a `modal` if a certain state is `false`. It would be most convenient to use the link because its inside `ul>li` element but prolly you're right.